# Is there any possible way to get the Ender Dragon in Minecraft Xbox 360 edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm curious whether it's possible to get the Ender Dragon in Minecraft for Xbox 360 (without command blocks or hacking)

I've heard a few ways, but they haven't worked.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what these ways that haven't worked are? Saves people from wasting time suggesting the same things you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no way to simply 'summon' the Ender Dragon (safe for the new/summon command). Since only the PC Version has access to commands, that means it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to summon him outside of the End on Consoles.

Unless of course you are refering to how to get to the Ender Dragon, in that case, you need to find the End-Portal. That is done by gathering Eyes of Ender (Ender Pearl + Blaze Powder) and using them, as they will lead you to the portal. Once there, you need to activate the Portal Blocks by using said Eyes of Ender on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are currently no command blocks in minecraft xbox 360 but it is possible , but since u said hacking i dont now if this counts u have to download some mods for xbox 360 edition which if can give minecraft problems but if your trying in vanilla the answer is simply no.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are there actual mods for the MC360/PE or did you mean something else?

Comment: yes there are mods for pe

Comment: and xbox i just dont know how to download them